# `require': cannot load such file -- celluloid/current (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activesupport, celluloid

```
/Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:275:in `require': cannot load such file -- celluloid/current (LoadError)
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:275:in `block in require'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:275:in `require'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/pubnub-3.8.0/lib/pubnub.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /Users/siva/Desktop/projects/populere/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'


RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/siva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/siva/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3
     - /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
     - /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin
     - /Users/siva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin
     - /Users/siva/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/mysql/bin
```

I don't why `active_support` trying to take celluloid as dependency.

Comment: add using MAC with RVM

Comment: applying block code format to improved and make the question more clear

Comment: It is not ActiveSupport that is requiring celluloid. Looking the stack trace this line seems to be source of the issue.`from /Users/siva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/pubnub-3.8.0/lib/pubnub.rb:6`

You are using PubNub gem? It does have a dependency to celluloid. 

https://github.com/pubnub/ruby/blob/master/pubnub.gemspec

Answer (score 1):

After adding `pubnub` to your `Gemfile`, did you do `bundle install`?

Looks like `pubnub` has a dependency on `celluloid` which is requiring `celluloid/current` on line 6 of `pubnub-3.8.0/lib/pubnub.rb:6`.

If you do `bundle install` it ensures that all the `gems` defined in the `Gemfile` along with their dependencies are installed properly.

Refer to [pubnub](https://github.com/pubnub/ruby/blob/3.8.0/lib/pubnub.rb#L6) for more info.